# Apply an angularJS filter every 1 minute

Tags: json, angularjs, filter, timeout, intervals

I have a JSON file with all classes of a specific date, like the example below:

```
[{"start":"2015-11-16 13:50:00",
  "end":"2015-11-16 14:40:00",
  "classId":"156",
  "student":[{"name":"Eduardo",
              "id":"1",
              "isBirthday":"0"}]},
{"start":"2015-11-16 18:00:00",
"end":"2015-11-16 18:50:00",
"classId":"109",
"student":[{"name":"Mark",
            "id":"2",
            "isBirthday":"0"}]},
{"start":"2015-11-16 19:00:00",
"end":"2015-11-16 19:50:00",
"classId":"125",
"student":[{"name":"Allan",
            "id":"3",
            "isBirthday":"0"}]},
{"start":"2015-11-16 20:00:00",
"end":"2015-11-16 20:50:00",
"classId":"141",
"student":[{"name":"Macella",
            "id":"4",
            "isBirthday":"0"}]}]
```

I have to show in one DIV, the current class (I'm using momentJS to get the current time), and in another one, I have to show the next class. This is working, with ng-repeat and two filters.

Now, I have to let this to update when my current time changes and another class starts, so, this is why I want to know if it's possible with AngularJS and $timeout function calling a filter to update my webpage.

Is it possible? If not, how could I do something like this? Suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `calling a filter` exactly? You have to change your scope (say `$scope.classId`) and filters(ngRepeat filters?), will changed too(on next `$digest` call).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, when my page loads, my controller has an ajax call from where I get the JSON file. I want to avoid executing the ajax call every time, so I just want to filter the displayed (JSON file) data every minute instead of loading it again from server. Thank you @vp_arth!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Angularjs's [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval). This calls a function in your controller every time it goes off, and you can access and change `$scope` variables, without having to `.$apply()` changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.
You just update your scope and `filter` will automatically update visible collection.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucdgpcbL/4/)